# Pass useState setter function as a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm using `useState` within a React component and I would like to pass the setter to another function as part of a callback (this other function handles some logic which is not accessible within the component).

Here is the simplified code :

```
function init(canvas, cb) {
    ...
    // Call cb(...) based on internal logic
}

function MyComponent () {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [x, setX] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        init(canvas, function (v) {
            console.log(v);
            setX(v);
        });
    }, []);
    return <div>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="500" height="300"></canvas>
        <div}>{x}</div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem is, the value of `x` is not updated when the callback is called, except for the first time (when `x` stops being `null`).

I know it is called and I know `x` is updated because I can see the log in the console.
It's like the setter `setX` won't work or the component won't detect `x` has been updated.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: So to clarify, `init` calls `setX` correctly when the component loads? I think we need to see the whole `init` function.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. What exactly is wrong? Can you give an example?

```js
function init(canvas, cb) {
      cb(100)
}



function MyComponent () {
    const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [x, setX] = React.useState(null);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        
        init(canvas, function (v) {
            console.log(v);
            setX(v);
        });
    }, []);
    
    function handleOnClick() {
      init(canvasRef.current, function (v) {
        setX(prev => prev + v)
      })
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Change prop x</button>
        <div>{x}</div>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="500" height="100" />
        
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
canvas {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: OK I found my issue... in my case x was an object, and some of its attributes were rendered, which react can't handle well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do a similar thing in this [repl](https://repl.it/@AhmedGaafer/sof-react-ans1#src/App.js) it worked just fine.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function foo (cb, value){
  return cb(value);
}

function App (props){
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = v => {
    setX(v);
  }

  return(
    
    <div> 
      {x? x: "Hello World"} 
    
      <input type="button" value="Press Me" onClick={() => foo(handleClick, x+1)} /> 
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The use effect is only called once per state change and I am not seeing where do you call the state update inside the component.

If you mean that you want to change the sate of this component from an entirely different place then I suggest you use providers or [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)